# I'm having an error using modalroute can you solve the problem?

Tags: flutter, mobile, mobile-development

I'm getting an error in modal.route and I can't enter text, can you help?

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
VeriModeli iletilenArgumanlar = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Profil Sayfası")),
  body: Container(
    child: Column(children: [
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: cikisYap, child: Text("Çıkış Yap")),
      Text(iletilenArgumanlar.kullaniciaAdi),
      Text(iletilenArgumanlar.sifre),
    ]),
  ),
);
```

}
}

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {

VeriModeli? iletilenArgumanlar = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as VeriModeli?;

var cikisYap;
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Profil Sayfası")),
body: Container(
child: Column(children: [
ElevatedButton(onPressed: cikisYap, child: const Text("Çıkış Yap")),
Text(iletilenArgumanlar!.kullaniciaAdi),
Text(iletilenArgumanlar.sifre),
]),
),
);
}

if you still facing the error then call the arg like this "${iletilenArgumanlar}"